# How do I find logs specific to a single MapReduce job on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The application I'm working on has a lot of mapreduce cron jobs running, and from time to time some of them produce errors (mosty ApplicationErrors, TransientErrors, DatabaseErrors, TimeOuts, etc), that are somewhat sporadic and for the most part don't bother me.

However, while debugging and testing, I find it's impossible to attribute which jobs caused which errors. The logs usually just give me the instance, but no hint even to the id of the job. The url is just the generic /mapreduce/worker_callback so no help there either.

I feel like I am missing something, or is there really no way of determining which log belongs to which MR pipeline, or the other way around - to find logs specific to a certain MR pipeline?

Comment: I don't have a sense of what your code looks like but perhaps you could add your own log entries (I havent used mapreduce yet so this is more a blind suggestion)

Comment: The problem is really twofold: For one, I find logs such as these http://pastebin.com/gAbDxFgx and have no clue which of the many MRs is causing it. And second, I want to look at already existing logging events from only one of my MapReduce jobs. For the second one, I'm looking into the logging module itself, as well as labels, but haven't found anything useful yet. For the first one, adding more logging on my own wouldn't help (if I'm not completely mistaken).

Comment: all i can think of is to go into mapreduce/base_handler.py etc and see if there is a way to add MR session/thread id to the logs- I dont know it well enough to give a definitive answer! Hopefully somebody will read the thread and help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your log, you have `task_name=appengine-mrshard-158112310423699B53FC1-22-0`. The `158112310423699B53FC1` part corresponds to a specific Job ID. The details for this Job can usually be found at url-to-your-app/mapreduce. That way, you can find the name that you have given to the job.

### View details for a job

To see the details for the specific Job ID (e.g. `158112310423699B53FC1`):

> appid.appspot.com/mapreduce/detail?mapreduce_id=158112310423699B53FC1

### View entire pipeline

Finding the root Pipeline ID from the Job ID is possible using the following steps.

1. Query the `_AE_MR_MapreduceState` table with the Job ID. Using the datastore viewer:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM _AE_MR_MapreduceState WHERE __key__ = Key('_AE_MR_MapreduceState','158112310423699B53FC1')
   ```

   The Pipeline ID can be found in the `mapreduce_spec` column as `pipeline_id`.
2. The found Pipeline ID is probably not the root pipeline ID. To find the root Pipeline ID, query `_AE_Pipeline_Record`. Using the datastore viewer:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM _AE_Pipeline_Record WHERE __key__ = Key('_AE_Pipeline_Record', '653a3bd9a90f11e28ff6a3556e435fbc')
   ```

   The column root_pipeline has the key the root Pipeline ID for the MapReduce job.
3. Finally, using the name of the root pipeline key, you can view the entire MapReduce pipeline here:

   > appid.appspot.com/mapreduce/pipeline/status?root=0607a90aa90f11e2bbfea3556e435fbc

Comment: Ha, great! I knew I was missing something. I just checked the pipeline ID, which is a hex string, but that didn't match anything in the logs. For reference, the details incl. job name, can be found at http://appid.appspot.com/mapreduce/detail?mapreduce_id=$TASK_ID. You don't happen to know a way to find the root pipeline from a given task id? I.e. instead of ending up at a shuffle pipeline I could easily check the status of its root?

Comment: I have found a way to find the root pipeline ID and have updated the answer since this involved a few steps. Hope it helps :-)